# Failure to create ZIP archive, but no error messages

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to create a ZIP archive of some image files. This directory of files, I have added to an array named `$valid`. Each item in this array is a string like so:

```
"uploads/1845_45678_862_speaker.jpg"
```

This is my code that I'm trying to work, to create a ZIP archive of all of these physical files:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "ptx_speakers.zip";

$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach ($valid as $zip_item) {
    $zip->addFile($zip_item);
}

$zip->close();
```

However, this isn't working. Even with error reporting turned on, I just get a blank screen. I tried the following code afterwards, but nothing displayed here either:

```
if (!file_exists($zip_name)) {
    "No file."
}
```

Can anyone see a fatal flaw in my code? I can paste more (like how I create the initial array) if you so wish.

Comment: Can you post some information on `ZipArchive`? Also, have you checked your log files?

Comment: `ZipArchive()` is a built in PHP class: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php, I also do not have access to the log files... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, my problem lied not in my script, but in my file/folder permissions. Since I had permission to upload the files in the first place, I assumed I would be able to write with this file, but no, I had to update it's permissions to `757` and then the script worked a charm first time.

Comment: Still, your code has a flaw because it doesn't check if it can write the ZIP file. If you've used the code from [this answer by 1nflktd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25688423/2629998) you'd have had an error that tells you about the permission issue.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone see a fatal flaw in my code?

Yes.

```
$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

is not working, and you are not checking for errors.

It should be something like

```
$res = $zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE); 
if($res === true){
    foreach ($valid as $zip_item) {
        $zip->addFile($zip_item);
    }
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo "Error creating zip file: " . $res;
}
```

If everything works fine, `$res` will be true, and move on to foreach, etc.

If not, it has one of [these values](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php#refsect1-ziparchive.open-returnvalues). Check it, and you will see what is wrong.

In your code, you are doing

```
$zip->addFile($zip_item);
```

but the zip file is not created, what will cause some error.